Flutter Camera Impacts the performance and quality
I am working in the flutter application and I have the functionality of the camera in my app. I am using camera plugin but it is not up to the mark. camera plugin impacts the performance of my app. also the image quality is not good. even though I am using the high quality resolution.
I have tried the different plugins. still there is no improvement.
does anyone have any idea to improve quality and performance of camera functionality in my flutter app?
